# PID tuning for system with parameter

Tags: control-theory

How can I tune a PID to control a system with a parameter? Can I know beforehand how to change the PID parameters in function of the value of the system parameter?

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear rule for this but generally P is used to make the system faster, I is used to get rid of steady state error and D is used to reduced the overshoot.

Comment: Indeed. I just wondered if you can determine the influence of a parameter in the system model on the PID tuning.